# Kafka - redriving events in an error topic

Tags: apache-kafka

We've implemented some resilience in our kafka consumer by having a main topic, a retry topic and an error topic as [outlined in this blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/error-handling-patterns-in-kafka/).

I'm wondering what patterns teams are using out there to redrive events in the error topic back into the retry topic for reprocessing. Do you use some kind of GUI to help do this redrive? I foresee a need to potentially append all events from the error topic into the retry topic, but also to selectively skip certain events in the error topic if they can't be reprocessed.

Answer (score 1):

Two patterns I've seen

- redeploy the app with a new topic config (via environment variables or other external config).
- Or use a scheduled task within the code that checks the upstream DLQ topic(s)

If you want to use a GUI, that's fine, but seems like more work for little gain as there's no tooling already built around that